# Correct JSON format in the sample

Tags: json

I am trying to convert this sample to json format and tried various json validators online.

The validators indicate the syntax in wrong but does not provide an example on how to resolve.

**sample**

```
 {"date": "5/8/2020", "time": "7:57:47 AM", "client": "187.45.18.205", "flags": "A", "query": "v1.addthisedge.com"}{"date": "5/8/2020", "time": "7:57:47 AM", "client": "188.35.138.205", "flags": "A", "query": "m.addthis.com"}{"date": "5/8/2020", "time": "7:57:47 AM", "client": "186.95.16.121", "flags": "A", "query": "cloud.acrobat.com"}
```

what is the correct json format in the sample above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct format of your JSON and its validated. The sample is a `JSONArray` object. In `JSONArray` each object will be separated by `comma(,)` and also covered with third parenthesis `[]` on the beginning and the end.

```
[
   {
      "date":"5/8/2020",
      "time":"7:57:47 AM",
      "client":"187.45.18.205",
      "flags":"A",
      "query":"v1.addthisedge.com"
   },
   {
      "date":"5/8/2020",
      "time":"7:57:47 AM",
      "client":"188.35.138.205",
      "flags":"A",
      "query":"m.addthis.com"
   },
   {
      "date":"5/8/2020",
      "time":"7:57:47 AM",
      "client":"186.95.16.121",
      "flags":"A",
      "query":"cloud.acrobat.com"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[{
    "date": "5/8/2020",
    "time": "7:57:47 AM",
    "client": "187.45.18.205",
    "flags": "A",
    "query": "v1.addthisedge.com"
}, {
    "date": "5/8/2020",
    "time": "7:57:47 AM",
    "client": "188.35.138.205",
    "flags": "A",
    "query": "m.addthis.com"
}, {
    "date": "5/8/2020",
    "time": "7:57:47 AM",
    "client": "186.95.16.121",
    "flags": "A",
    "query": "cloud.acrobat.com"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to Parse JSON, make sure your JSON objects are separeted by commas like this 
`...,"query": "cloud.acrobat.com"},{"date": "5/8/2020",...` and the whole object is enclosed in array [{...},{...},{...}] like this

```
[
  {
    "date": "5/8/2020",
    "time": "7:57:47 AM",
    "client": "187.45.18.205",
    "flags": "A",
    "query": "v1.addthisedge.com"
  },
  {
    "date": "5/8/2020",
    "time": "7:57:47 AM",
    "client": "188.35.138.205",
    "flags": "A",
    "query": "m.addthis.com"
  },
  {
    "date": "5/8/2020",
    "time": "7:57:47 AM",
    "client": "186.95.16.121",
    "flags": "A",
    "query": "cloud.acrobat.com"
  }
]
```